# condicionales en python

Tags: python, formato-condicional

Como le hago para que  en el input  que contiene un string con espacio, por ejemplo: **Green Tea**,  se pueda detectar para compararlo en un condicional en *Python*.

```
print("WELCOME TO THE MONOS RESTAURANT")
print("HERE IS THE MENU :")

menu = ['Pasta',
'Bolognese',
'Pesto',
'Pea soup',
'Smoked Salmon',
'Mushroom pide',
'Green Curry',
'Fried tofu']

print(menu)

food_order = str(input("Please enter your order:").title())
if food_order in menu:
    print(f"Yes we have {food_order.title()}.")
else:
    print(f"Sorry we don't serve {food_order.title()}.")
```

Comment: solo leelo con `var = input("ingresa producto: ")`. Por defecto se llerá como string con todo y espacios

Comment: Como dice Luis Felipe, y además leera el '\r' (Enter) con que terminas el string.